# Word for presage/portend but with a positive context?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, doing well in school ____ future success. Predict doesn't have a positive connotation, like presage and portend have a negative one.

Comment: "presage" doesn't have a negative connotation. One of the examples in Merriam-Webster is "the sight of the first robin is always a welcome presage of spring".

Answer (score 4):

> Doing well in school *promises* future success.

'To promise' can be used even if the outcome is not certain:

> 4: to suggest beforehand : give promise of
>   dark clouds promise rain

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/promise)

and (when used with positive 'arguments') it has a more positive connotation than 'to predict'.